# D3 Graph displays no graph despite no errors (REACT)

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

Im trying to port the code from https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/correlogram_scatter.html to react.

Now I know there are multiple things I need to change such that I don't create a new SVG on every new re-render, I just wanted to make sure I could get the example graph working before I started to make changes.

However nothing renders, and the console has no errors which makes debugging this very difficult.

I threw an example into code sandbox that seems to mimic what I see on my end.

What am I missing?

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-haze-9excy?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like what this might need to get over the finish line is wrapping our D3 code in React's `useEffect` hook.

[Here's an updated, working Codesandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-water-8cd4t)

We can call `useEffect` initially and we can pass any data we'd like to observe for our chart in the array that `useEffect` takes as an argument.

This works well because `useEffect` is called the first time that DOM elements have been rendered, which is why  it's the best time to access the DOM element living in the properties of the `svg` ref.

Every time your component renders, it calls `useEffect`. You can watch for changes by passing arguments into its array, but if you only want to run `useEffect` the very first time the component mounts, you can leave that array empty.

In my experience, this has been a helpful pattern:

```
function YourChartCode({ data, property }) {
  const yourRef = useRef();

  // will be called initially and on every data change
  useEffect(() => {
    const svg = d3.select(yourRef.current);
    
    // do D3 stuff here
    // leave array empty or pass arguments you're watching into this array
  }, [data, dimensions, property])

 return (
  <svg ref={yourRef}></svg>
 )
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you for taking the time out to help me, is there a reason however that only one of the scatterplots gets rendered? The example d3 code has a scatterplot for comparing one of the four constraints to another

Comment: The loop is definitely building each plot, so it seems like this has to do with the order in which the `g` element that each iteration of the loop creates not having the correct properties applied.

Check out dev tools:

https://imgur.com/O8dsZhs

https://imgur.com/mF8Vd1l

Comment: Thanks again, given that you answered my question Ive marked this as correct, Ill use what you've showed here and try and figure out this g element issue you pointed out